# Annualize a covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix

I am attempting to find the annualized covariance between assets in a portfolio but I only have daily data. So how do I annualize the covariance matrix between these assets?

Comment: multiply each entry by 252, the number of trading days in a year